# My reference image not showing up in blender

Tags: image

I have seen another post on this topic, but I couldn't find the solution. I'm following YouTube tutorials and added the image the same way they did but the image never shows up. When I switch the tab to texture paint mode I can see the picture, but with any other mode I can only see the yellow border of the image.
Moreover when I started a fresh project and tried adding the image, it is working fine.
Are any of my options disabled in my original project? Please help as I'm stuck and can't go further without solving this issue.
I have made sure my image is jpg.

[image: I have attached my image]

[Here's the .blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UoLp2ue2QLT1kXYQzOb6oKS8kZhc7t4o)

Comment: Would be great if you can share your blend file

Comment: i have added my .blend file

Comment: I'm getting a 404 error when clicking your .blend file.
Please use https://blend-exchange.com/ for sharing your .blend file.

Answer (score 4):

*Show Overlays* was turned off by accident:

[image]

Comment: Hi and Welcome @Vinurk. Consider that this is not a regular forum. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and then select *Cursor to World Origin*. I did it on your blend file and it worked.

[image]

Comment: What!!! Im still not able to view the image. It only comes in the texture paint mode

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the name of the image file is the problem.

[image]

I had the filename named "Top" at first. I changed it to "Top_View" and the image showed up.

Answer (score 0):

Image objects display requires that *Overlays* and its nested item *Objects Extras* both be turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your viewport shading to *Material Preview* and here it is, now your image will be visible